# Shared service can't reach variables from component

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding

I'm trying to call functions from external components on a custom selector. I've found a method to achieve this, but it won't recognize any of the variables from the component. This is what I've done:

Selector (declared as an entry component):

**HTML**:

```
<button (click)="addCertificate(searchInput)">Add</button>
```

**TS**:

```
constructor(public sharedService: SharedFilterService ) {
}

public addCertificate(payload: any) {

    console.log("Step 1") // This is executed

    if (this.sharedService.add_LicenceComponent) {

        console.log("Step 2") // This one too
        this.sharedService.add_LicenceComponent(payload);
    }
}
```

Service (declared as a provider):

**TS**:

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedFilterService {

    public add_LicenceComponent: any;

    constructor() { }
}
```

And finally the component (Licence) where I can't reach any variable:

**TS**:

```
  constructor(public dialogService: DialogService, public sharedService: SharedFilterService) {
      this.sharedService.add_LicenceComponent = this.addLicence;
     }

  addLicence(licence: any): void {
    console.log("Step 3") // Printed too
    this.dialogService.openDialog(DialogComponent, licence).afterClosed().subscribe(); // Here I get this: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'openDialog' of undefined
  }
```

The service is just a mediator. I'm using a selector (the buttom calling addCertificate) inside of the Licence component

Comment: Instead of `this.sharedService.add_LicenceComponent(payload);` you simply need to say `this.sharedService.add_LicenceComponent = payload;`, because `add_LicenceComponent` is just a variable.

Comment: how do you call `addLicence` function and from where ?

Comment: What I believe is in last piece `dialogService` is yet not initialized when `addLicence` function is being called. You can check, dialogService must be undefined. is it ?

Comment: @Batajus add_LicenceComponent is a function (the one I'm calling in the last step, I can print the value there, but I can't reach "dialogService").

I'm calling addLicence using the shared service variable

Comment: are you getting any compilation error or run time console errors..?

Comment: It compiles just fine. dialogService is undefined as I stated on a comment in the code. The service is just a mediator. I'm using a selector (the buttom calling addCertificate) inside of the Licence component, shouldn't "dialogService" be initialized already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign function for `add_LicenceComponent` of **sharedService** instead returning void.

Another thing is your getting *TypeError* because of service not initialised while trying to access it in ***constructor***. Move it to ***ngOnInit()*** and do check do whether you added them in providers

You need to do some modifications in your component code like below,

```
 constructor(public dialogService: DialogService, public sharedService: SharedFilterService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.sharedService.add_LicenceComponent = this.addLicence;
  } 

  addLicence(licence: any) {
    console.log("Step 3") // Printed too
    return (licence) => this.dialogService.openDialog(DialogComponent, licence).afterClosed().subscribe();
  }
```

You can check sample impl in this [**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-svwbxb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)